# Show notification icon context menu after performing some action

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, notification-area

I need to show the context menu for my notification icon context menu for both left and right clicks after performing some actions rather than right after the click.

It works perfectly for the left-click as:

```
sysTrayIcon.MouseClick += OnSysTrayClicked;

private static void OnSysTrayClicked(Object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        PerformActions();
        MethodInfo oMethodInfo = typeof(NotifyIcon).GetMethod("ShowContextMenu", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        oMethodInfo.Invoke(sysTrayIcon, null);
    }
}
```

But the right-click is still handled automatically and the associated `ContextMenuStrip` is shown at the right-click. Is there some way to override that with my event handler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two options.

Option A: Do not assign the context menu to this.ContextMenuStrip. Open the context menu manually whenever you want to. Be aware, that strip.Top and strip.Left must be absolute screen coordinates.

Option B: De-assign this.ContextMenuStrip OnMouseDown if right-mouse-button and re-assign OnMouseUp. See this [example](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/111097/How-to-disable-the-pop-up-of-ContextMenuStrip).

Comment: Tried Option B. It worked perfectly. Thanks!

PS: Do you know how Windows shows the context menu automatically? Shouldn't it check for and try to show the context menu after MouseUp itself?

Comment: As far as I know it hooks on the Mouse-right-click and calls contextMenu.Show(...) then. There is not way to hook up in between. Usually you can hook on contextMenu.Opening and set args.Cancel to true if you don't want the menu to be displayed.